# How to load angularjs directive use $injector

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-injector

I'm trying to use directive from other modules that is loaded by `angular.injector` but angular can't understand directives that is in `other_module`.
In my main file, I declare my module.

```
  angular.module('blockApp', []).directive('', []);
```

In second file, I try to add angularCharts as dependency:

```
  var otherBlock = angular.module('blockApp');
  otherBlock.run(function() {
      angular.injector(['ng', 'angularCharts']);
  });
```

Then I use `angularCharts`'s directives but angularjs can't identify them.
I know we should add dependent modules when we declare module but it is special case.

Comment: You can get it.. Well you need to `get` it. `angular.injector(['ng', 'other_module']).get('directiveNameDirective');` postFix directive name with "Directive"

Comment: Thanks PSL but it got `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $rootElementProvider <- $rootElement <- acChartDirective`.  
In my case your suggestion is `angular.injector(['ng', 'angularCharts']).get('acChartDirective');`

Comment: @PSL `angular.injector(['ng','other_module']).get('directiveNameDirectirve)` calls to `other_module.directive('directiveName, function() {})` but angular still doesn't understand `directiveName`. I think we still need register `directiveName` to angular...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Q5oD65wSvBAemf5BCDL7?p=preview

In this case you can use $compile (you still need a $scope from the example, but $compile pretty much answers your question I guess),

```
    var $compile = chartsInjector.get("$compile");
    console.log("$compile=",$compile);

    var chartsDirective = $compile("<div charts></div>");
    console.log(chartsDirective);
```

...

```
  var blockapp = angular.module('blockApp', []); 
  blockapp.run(function(){
    // create a new injector
    var chartsInjector = angular.injector(['ng', 'angularCharts']);
    console.log("chartsInjector=",chartsInjector);

    var $compile = chartsInjector.get("$compile");
    console.log("$compile=",$compile);

    var chartsDirective = $compile("<div charts></div>");
    console.log(chartsDirective);
  })
```

### note that you will be creating multiple injectors here.

injector 1) created by ng-app

```
<body ng-app="blockApp">
```

injector 2) created by angular.injector()

```
var chartsInjector = angular.injector(['ng', 'angularCharts']);
```

## whole code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // creating the angularcharts
      angular.module('angularCharts', []).directive('charts', function(){
        return function(){}
      }); 

      // creating blockapp
      angular.module('blockApp', []).directive('', []); 

      // retrieving the created blockapp
      // NOTE! ng-app will create a new injector for blockapp 
      var blockapp = angular.module('blockApp', []); 
      blockapp.run(function(){
        // create a new injector
        var chartsInjector = angular.injector(['ng', 'angularCharts']);
        console.log("chartsInjector=",chartsInjector);

        var $compile = chartsInjector.get("$compile");
        console.log("$compile=",$compile);

        var chartsDirective = $compile("<div charts></div>");
        console.log(chartsDirective);
      })

    </script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="blockApp">

  </body>

</html>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Q5oD65wSvBAemf5BCDL7?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Noypi, your solution can resolve my problem. Is there any way angularjs can compile `charts` automatically from template instead of using $compile?  Also why do you know `$injector.get` can get `$compile`, I was thinking it only get services from modules?  Thanks again :)

Comment: Glad to have helped. If you open "docs.angularjs.org/api", at the left side are the default services delivered by the "ng" module. Those services should be available. When I tried the "template" parameter in the directive's definition object, directives I placed there gets compiled when the directive gets compiled.

Comment: ah yes, there is also a $templateCache service, check it out... https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache